# jQuery change different values with multiple drop-down lists in same file

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I had a simple solution by updating the value of a div and a button at the same time by selection a vlaue of a drop-down list. 
It's like selection 1 = 10$ and button link is http://one.com
and selection 2 = 20$ and button link is http://two.com

It looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
  <div id="price_div">10$</div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="span2"><select id="duaration_div" onChange="update();">
        <option value="0" SELECTED>One
        <option value="1" >Two
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><a href="http://one.com"></a></td>
  </tr>
```

jquery:

```
//price function
  var alpha=new Array(
    "10$",
    "20$"
  );

  function update(){
    document.getElementById("price_div").innerHTML=alpha[document.getElementById("duaration_div").value];


 //button function

  var button=new Array(
        '<a class="btn " type="button" href="http://www.one.com/" target="_self">One</a>',
        '<a class="btn " type="button" href="http://www.two.com/" target="_self">Two</a>'
  );
    document.getElementById("button_div").innerHTML=button[document.getElementById("duaration_div").value];
  }
```

Now I have a form with 3 different price and 3 different button links.
But I have no clue how to build a concept for it in jquery. I want each drop-down to change a specific field and button. But how do I do that?

This is my HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
  <div id="price_div">10$</div>
  <div id="price_div">50$</div>
  <div id="price_div">200$</div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="span2"><select id="duaration_div" onChange="update();">
        <option value="0" SELECTED>One
        <option value="1" >Two
      </select></td>
    <td class="span2"><select id="beta" onChange="update();">
        <option value="2" SELECTED>One
        <option value="3" >Two
      </select></td>
    <td class="span2"><select id="gamma" onChange="update();">
        <option value="4" SELECTED>Test One
        <option value="5" >Test Two
      </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><a href="http://one.com"></a></td> /* and two.com */
   <td><a href="http://three.com"></a></td> /*and four.com */
   <td><a href="http://five.com"></a></td> /* and six.com*/
  </tr>
  </table>
```

How does the jQuery code looks like for changing each value by specific drop-down in the same file (price 1 and 2 / drop-down 1, price 3 and 4 / drop-down 2 etc.)

Any Idea?

thx!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly....

```
$('#gamma').val(4);
$('#beta').val(4);
```

Or to change them all at once:

```
$('select').val(0);
```